# Is a user query containing the string "\u0600\u0000bՕR" suspicious/malicious?

Tags: injection, json

Recently, one of my services received a query where the JSON payload contained the string `<an-arabic-character>\u0000bՕR`. The service handled it gracefully so no real harm was done, but am I right to be suspicious of this activity ?

To make it fully clear, the first character is the "Arabic number sign" and has UTF-16 encoding `06 00`, but this site won't allow me to actually use that character in this question.

The apparent null byte is specifically 'spelled out' as such in typical Java/JavaScript notation. That, combined with the fact that `60` is the backtick character and the specific mention of `OR`, makes me think this might be an attempt to slip in a crafted message.

---

I have received a second query with a similar, though not the same, contents. Instead of the bՕR with Armenian Օ, as commented, it ends in `bֽT` (Unicode: `b\05BD T`). The full UTF-8 representations are:

- D8 80 5C 75 30 30 30 30 62 D5 95 52 for the `bՕR` message
- D8 80 5C 75 30 30 30 30 62 D6 BD 54 for the `bֽT` message

I should also note that the message may not malicious, because the same call can be made by client services. In that case, the client system is trying (and failing) to send a Date-like object in the JSON payload.

I have added some more logging to the service, so that I can get more clarity on what is going on and who or what is sending this request.

Comment: That's not the Latin "O". It is [Armenian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D5%95).

Comment: There are definitely vulnerabilities involving unicode translations... or just for bypassing validation of input.  For instance, the traversal attack mentioned here: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Path_Traversal & https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Unicode_Encoding

Comment: This could also just be an app that's reading a file and not processing a byte-order-marker. (some files have them and some do not... the standard isn't followed very well)  From Wikipedia: "The BOM for little-endian UTF-32 is the same pattern as a little-endian UTF-16 BOM followed by a NUL character, an unusual example of the BOM being the same pattern in two different encodings. Programmers using the BOM to identify the encoding will have to decide whether UTF-32 or a NUL first character is more likely."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery (mostly) solved. It was indeed one of the client applications sending a badly encoded Date, rather than a malicious actor. I will have to find exactly how the wrong value is attained, but the screenshot below amateurishly shows how we got to the byte value of one of the reported strings. The other one also checks out according to the same logic.

[image: from a date to a wrongly encoded byte string]

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever used null characters when trying to do something sneaky while pentesting. I cannot imagine a case where your average user would accidentally inject one, even with funky character sets.